# Subclass compilation in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, compile-time

I have read that Inheritance is a "compile-time' phenomenon. Also in a different place I have read that the superclass code is loaded by classloader, which I deduce happens at run-time. This is causing me some confusion regarding the nature of inheritance. Does the class file of sublass contain the actual compiled code  of superclass, or is it accessed at run-time?

Comment: "I have read...": Can you provide a reference?

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lavender/courses/tutorial/java-06.pdf

Comment: I can see why that increased your confusion. As the other answers point out, inheritance matters both at compile time and runtime. That sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

So consider you create a class that inherits a class that is included in a 3rd party jar file.

In order to compile your code you need to have the 3rd party jar file in the classpath of your compiler.

In order to run your code you will also need the jar file in the classpath of the java command that launches the application.

Your subclass does not contain the code of the superclass, it is in the jar files. Your compiled class contains a reference to the superclass. When your class is loaded by the classloader it searches the classpath for the superclass and loads it.

Comment: I think your answer might hit his confusion better, but I think he's stumbling over the idea that it's an either or proposition, when it is not.  It is both.  It is required at compile time in order to be compiled, and required at runtime in order to be loaded and linked.

Comment: @lscoughlin Agreed. I don't think of language concepts like this as either compile-time or runtime.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Iscoughlin, that clears my doubts...@Iscoughlin is correct, I was wondering whether its an either or proposition, your comment clears the air.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read it's compile time? I guess if you're compiling your subclass then yes, it needs to have a superclass to reference when being compiled.

But when you actually run the code it is dynamically linked as per:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html

"The Java Virtual Machine dynamically loads, links and initializes classes and interfaces"

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lavender/courses/tutorial/java-06.pdf I read it in this PDF file, in the first line. That increased my confusion.